# Finding the derivative of $f(x)=x -\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))$, question about the characteristics of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So exercise goes as follows:

> Find the derivative of $f(x) = x-\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))$. What does your answer imply about $f(x)$? calculate $f(0)$ and $f(\pi)$. Is there a contradiction?

This is explained in the formula:

"if $x \ne −(k +1/2)\pi$, $k \in \Bbb Z$. Thus, $f$ is
constant on intervals not containing odd multiples of $\pi/2$.
$f (0) = 0$ but $f (\pi ) = \pi − 0 = \pi$. There is no contradiction
here because $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})$
is not defined, so $f$ is not constant on the interval containing $0$ and $\pi$."

I was hoping that somebody could explain what he means with:

"There is no contradiction here because $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})$
is not defined, so $f$ is not constant on the interval containing $0$ and $\pi$."

I know that the inverse of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is defined on the interval $x\in (-\infty, +\infty)$ and $y\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

and derivative of $f(x)=x -\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))$ is $f'(x) = 0$

Help would be highly appriciated!

Comment: It's not even so much that $f'(\pi/2)$ is not defined, it's that $f(\pi/2)$ doesn't exist there. This is because $\tan(\pi/2)$ does not exist. So the function has jump discontinuities at $\pi/2, 3\pi/2, ...$ even though the derivative is zero everywhere the function is differentiable.

Comment: @user296602 $f'(x)$ is not zero everywhere though

Comment: @Dylan It is zero everywhere the function is defined, though.

Comment: @user296602 Nevermind. I was confused between $f$ and $f'$. $f$ is not zero everywhere, but $f'$ is

Answer (score 1):

The function initially appears to satisfy the following corollary of the Mean Value Theorem (or Rolle's Theorem):

> Suppose $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, with $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. Then $f$ is constant.

So, we have $f$, defined (mostly) on $[0, \pi]$ with a derivative defined (mostly) on $(0, \pi)$ where the derivative is $0$ everywhere it's defined. However, the function is not constant. This isn't strictly enough to contradict the above corollary (as the "mostly" indicated). Our function $f$ fails to be defined at $\pi/2$, as does $f'$ of course. This is because $\tan$ is undefined when you plug in $\pi/2$.

It's hard to say definitely why something is **not** a contradiction, because it assumes that there's some "obvious" reason why it appears there should be a contradiction. Plenty of people would look at it and think, because of the above corollary, that the function should probably be constant, but plenty of others would recognise immediately that the above corollary doesn't apply, and would know not to expect the function to be constant.

Anyway, I think this is what the question is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

In places in which $x = −(k +1/2)\pi$, $k \in \Bbb Z$, a value and derivative not exist. But in places $x \ne -(k+1/2)\pi$ we have always a value well defined and derivative, which is here 0. Values on this values is multiple of $\pi$. From $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$ this value is $\pi$, after step to $2\pi$, etc...
$F(x)=k\pi$ if $(k-1/2)\pi<x<(k+1/2)\pi$

Comment: So all that this is saying is that because the function is not defined on $\frac{\pi}{2}$(or any multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for that matter) it's not a constant on that interval?

Comment: Yes. And it is not a contradiction, if in this places y - value steps.